# How to make a DIV from a JQuery Slidedown close onclick of a different one?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, slidedown

I am doing a Jquery SlideDown on Multiple Dvi ID and this is the code that I have. It works really well however, I would like to see if it is possible to make the opened div close as you open another one. Note: I will be using more then two divs.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a.slidecontrol').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var divID = $this.attr("id").replace("slidecontrol_", "slidedisplay_");
        var $div = $('#'+divID);
        if ($div.is(':visible')) {
            $div.slideUp(500);
        } else {
            $div.slideDown(500);
        }
        return false;
    });

});
</script> 



</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="slidecontrol_1" class="slidecontrol">Read More</a>

<div id="slidedisplay_1" style="display:none;">Display #1</div>

<hr/>

<a href="#" id="slidecontrol_2" class="slidecontrol">Read More 2</a>

<div id="slidedisplay_2" style="display:none;">Display #2</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!
Sophie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all of your `slidedisplay_` elements the class `display`, and change your code to:

```
$('a.slidecontrol').click(function(){
$(".display").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
/* Rest of your click code here */
});
```